# MS Project files opening in read only mode

Tags: document-library, project2007

I've got a user who has Project 2007 files stored in their MOSS 2007 team site.  He checks out the file out and then says Edit in Microsoft Project.  When the file opens, it opens in read only mode.  In order to save changes, he has to save the file locally then upload it to the document library.

The user is using a Windows 7 VM inside a Mac with IE9.  Any ideas why this happens?  Other office documents in Office 2010 open without isue in edit mode.

Note: we are **not** using project server and it isn't displaying the message the file is locked for editing like most search results are coming up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this computer did not have the Sharepoint domain listed in the trusted sites.  Once it was added, the use local drafts folder became available when the file was checked out and opened, and subsequently opened in edit mode.

Hopefully that helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There's an Office 2013 fix for this:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/projectsupport/2015/01/06/saving-projects-to-sharepointand-opening-them-again-part-1/

Comment: Please to do not post just link.. put some extracts as links might go down