# SharePoint document library issue in document check in - check out

Tags: document-library, check-out

We are using SharePoint 2007.

I have created a new document library and added some documents.
When I checked out any document, it throws following error message

> "This document could not be done checked out to your local drafts
>   folder.The document may have already been checked out, or the local
>   drafts folder could not be written to"

but even after getting this message that document gets checked out and if I open it then it gets open in Reading mode instead of Edit mode and shows following error

> "This modification is not allowed because the selection is locked"

I have tried following

1) Set Enable Client Integration to Yes from Central Admin but got no success.
What is the reason behind it and how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you please let us the client configuration (OS Version , Office Version , Browser Version) and also the file name and extension trying to checkout ? Also does this happen to the specific file OR all the files?? Did you try the the same in other machines too(with diff or same config)?

Comment: Check this similar thread http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22216/ms-project-files-opening-in-read-only-mode

Comment: Hi Vamsi,Thanks for response.

Our configuration is Windows 7,Office 2007 and IE 8.
This checkout error occur only for Word and excel files,for PDF it works fine.
Yes we tried this on different machines but same error message occurs.