# Sharepoint Check In Check Out Malfunctioning

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Good Day, on our sharepoint portal, Whenever we check out Word Files, or Excel Files, It throws a message: **"This document could not be checked out to your local drafts folder.This may already have been checked out, or the local drafts folder could not be written to."**

The documents in Question, have not been checked out before. Also, The main thing, which is troubling me is that after checking out, all the files open in read only mode and cannot be edited.

Is there some configuration which has to be changed, to get the check in-check out functioning again? Please suggest some good articles....Please Help!!

Comment: Is there any setting which needs to be changed on the server?

Comment: Is this happening on all documents with all users?

Answer (score 1):

I find this feature often breaks, so I just disable it. It's done from the Office client program in question in the Options page:

http://joranmarkx.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/disable-check-out-to-local-drafts-folder/

Answer (score 0):

Is the sharepoint doamin in the list of trusted sites on the browser? See [this recent submission](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22216/ms-project-files-opening-in-read-only-mode) of mine where I was running into the same issue.

Comment: Hi PirateEric,Thanks for your response! The sharepoint domain is,infact in the list of trusted sites on the browser.This did not unfortunately, solve our problem. Is there another possible solution to this issue?